# Can "秀气" be used to describe objects that aren't people?

Tags: usage

So there are 3 main translations for 秀气:

1. Delicate
2. Elegant
3. Graceful

Which makes it seem like it could be used to describe really anything--
However I have a friend who is saying that it is normally used only to describe people.

Is it not an adjective I could use to describe non-people-- like an elegant wristwatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [秀气](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A7%80%E6%B0%94)
>
> 基本解释:
>
> 1. 样子清秀 (elegant appearance)
> 2. 言谈文雅,举止优美 (elegant demeanor)
> 3. (器物）小巧灵便 (elegant, exquisite object)
> 4. 灵秀之气 (elegant feel)；秀美(elegant)。小巧而清秀 (delicate)

(1) and (2) definition are mostly used to describe people

(3) definition said it can be used to describe 器物 (object)

Example:

*秀气的刺繡  (delicate embroidery)*

*秀气的雕塑  (delicate sculpture)*

(4) definition said it describes something that emit delicate, elegant or graceful feel

Example:

*秀氣的山水 = 山明水秀 (exquisite landscape)*

*秀气的文章 (elegantly written article)*

*寫得一手秀氣的字 (able to write elegant hand written words)*

Answer (score 0):

I also heard that it is usually used to describe people; however, it does seem possible to describe inanimate objects - such as wristwatches - using 秀气（according to Pleco, at least):

[image: pleco definition for 秀气]